# Typescript interface with private members

Tags: typescript

Why typescript not supporting private members in interfaces?

How to handle the following scenario?

```
interface IFoo
{
  private member: {};
}

class Foo implements IFoo
{
  private member = {};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Interfaces define "public contracts", it describes the public side of the class  and as such it doesn't make sense to have private access modifier.

[From Typescript interface documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> This prohibits you from using them to check that a class also has
>   particular types for the private side of the class instance.

---

But an interface can extend classes with private members.

From [Understanding TypeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890374.aspx):

> In TypeScript, interfaces can also extend classes, but only in a way
>   that involves inheritance. When an interface extends a class, the
>   interface includes all class members (public and private), but without
>   the class’ implementations.

```
class Customer
{
  private id: number;
  get Id(): number
  {
    return this.id
  }
  set Id( value: number )
  {
    this.id = value;
  }
}
interface ICustomer extends Customer
{
  MiddleName: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but isn't this considered a weakness of the language?

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal in what way? It makes very little sense to check if the instance itself implements something, you can see it yourself right in your editor already.

Comment: I understand that the focus of TypeScript interfaces is to create public contracts, so that objects within a running application inter-operate appropriately with one another. However, I think some would still find benefits if interfaces also specify the private side of a class. Private contracts ensure that the objects within a running application _intra-operate_ appropriately with themselves.