# I can't make a class field implemented from interface private, nor make interface field private

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I have this fields on the interface:

```
// Stores the to views folder
VIEW_PATH: string;
// Stores BrowserWindows with respective view  
browserWindows: [string, BrowserWindow | null][];
```

When I implement the fields in my class and try to set them private, I get this error:

```
Class 'WindowHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'IWindowHandler'.
  Property 'VIEW_PATH' is private in type 'WindowHandler' but not in type 'IWindowHandler'.ts(2420)
```

When I try to set the interface fields to private:

```
'private' modifier cannot appear on a type member.ts(1070)
```

Comment: Why do you want to make them private?

Comment: So they can't be accessed...

Comment: if they can't be accessed - then remove them from interface.

Comment: but its kinda strange, because the Interface should have that fields

Comment: Should be possible to make them private

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no sense. Your interface says `every class which implements me has this field which you can access` and then the class says `oh by the way you can't access this field`. You have to choose which one you actually want, provide the field publicly by declaring it in the interface or hide it, by not declaring it in the interface.

Comment: You're getting the wrong picture, I don't want to make the fields private directly on interface, but on the class, which implemented from iinterface. On Java its possible to do this, so that's why I'm asking

Comment: In TS not only classes implement interfaces, but POJOs as well. To summarise it: TS does not provide such a capability; for TS it would make no sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks @zerkms :) If you want, go ahead and your aswner to this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interfaces are by their nature public, and therefore can only have public members, so they are not accepting private/protected etc. definitions. On the other hand, the implementation of an interface, such as a class, can have private members/methods for its implementation details.

You probably either have misunderstood the concept of Interfaces, which are a kind of 'contract' between you and the public world, and therefore there is no logical use of 'hidden' elements in those contracts or you are trying to use them in an incorrect way. Let me know what is your use case and why you want some members to be private in order to further help you out.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the deep and comphreensive answer. I have now the picture in my head of what you're saying, and It makes sense. I was suprised because on Java you can set a implemented member to private or public, so, I was wondering if I could still do this in TypeScript.

Comment: Oh, now I see why you thought that way, because interfaces in Java 9 have become much more complex than a usual interface. They  can also have implementations of methods inside of them too. This made them very complex beasts, and that is why Java 9 had to introduce the concept of private methods to them. Because of the mixed implementation AND interface concept. That's not the case with Interface in Typescript, those interfaces are just the usual prescription of how a class should implement stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplementary answer:

It is true that TypeScript interfaces only describe a public contract. In TS terms they describe the [*shape of values*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). The asker's attempt (they are also not the only ones who sought this - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25163) for example) to make interface members private stems from the fact that two unrelated classes with the same `private` member are considered incompatible despite being identical structurally.

Similar to the [handbook example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-typescripts-private), the following leads to a type error:

```ts
class A { private a : string = ""; }
class B { private a : string = ""; }

let a = new A();
a = new B(); //Types have separate declarations of a private property 'a'.
```

So does this, meaning private members *do* contribute to the shape of a class:

```ts
class C implements B { //Types have separate declarations of a private property 'a'.
  private a : string = "";
}
```

However, these classes do not "share the private side of their shape from the same declaration" (ibid.). Only a subclass can share the private side of the shape with its superclass:

```ts
class D extends B { //OK
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

So, only classes have `private` members. This is also unlikely to change as a proposal for allowing interfaces to implement `protected` members (which is very similar in nature) [was declined as unsafe](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3854).

See also:

1. [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421741/11407695) on private members and interfaces.
2. Discussion on why `private` members [affect compatibility](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499).